# Missing AVD's in Target tab of Run Configuration

Tags: android, configuration, android-virtual-device

I have 3 AVD's set up, each for a different API level.  I want to make 3 corresponding run configurations for my project so I can easily test under each API level.  When I go to the target tab of the Run Configuration manager, I only see one of the available AVD's.  I can set it up as a Manual target selection and when I run it I can select from among the three AVD's, but I'd like to just set up 3 different Run Configurations.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new Run Configuration by clicking the white sheet icon on top of the left column, in Run Configurations window. Then you can choose your project and the avd. As far as I know you can't specify more than one avd for a run configuration.

EDIT:
anyway you won't see AVD's that use an API lower than your project target.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it was the project target that was the problem.  I had it set too high.